# QJsonValueRef vs. QJsonValue

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcore

In Qt's JSON implementation, in the `QJsonObject` class, there are two implementations of an operator (documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#operator-5b-5d)):

```
QJsonValue QJsonObject::operator[](const QString & key) const;
QJsonValueRef QJsonObject::operator[](const QString & key);
```

First off, what is the advantage here by returning `QJsonValueRef` as opposed to returning `QJsonValue`? Second, which value would be returned if I just said something like `root['time']`, where `root` is a `QJsonObject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid asking more than one question in a submitted question. That being said, here are the answers for your questions:

> Returns a reference to the value for key.
>
> The return value is of type QJsonValueRef, a helper class for QJsonArray and QJsonObject. When you get an object of type QJsonValueRef, you can use it as if it were a reference to a QJsonValue. If you assign to it, the assignment will apply to the element in the QJsonArray or QJsonObject from which you got the reference.

This means, you could call a method on the return value without having an interim object created explicitly by you in the code, just like how references work in C++.

As for the second sub-question, it depends on what the root object is. If it is a const object, the second, the non-const version, could not be called since that would violate the const correctness. Note the const here at the end:

```
> QJsonValue QJsonObject::operator[](const QString & key) const;
                                                          ^^^^^
```

For a mutable, aka. non-const object, you could call both, but by default the second version would be called. With some const casting, this could be changed, however.

Comment: Just to check, the `const` casting would go around `root`, right? Something like `((const)root)['time']`.

Comment: @saiarcot895: c++ has dedicated const cast.